# asynchronous call in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to call a function from my ui thread which fetches data from database. This takes a lot of time and I am trying to keep the ui responsive during this time.
I am using the following code:

```
        def onHit(self,evt):
            busy = PBI.PyBusyInfo(message, parent=self.Form.resultPage, title="Really Busy");
            wx.Yield();
            executor = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
            ##executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
            future = executor.submit(self.returnData);
            future.add_done_callback(self.onComplete);
        def onComplete(self,futures):
            #build a grid from futures.result()
            print future.result()
            #del busy
```

So I have 2 issues. First when I try to run this it says pickling error. Second, how do I delete busy in the second function when I dont have access to it? Does it make sense to declare it global or is there an easier way? Whats the best way to keep my ui responsive and update my ui after I have got the data from the sql databse? I dont mid using progress dialogs also.

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 373, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
```

Comment: For getting `busy`, I think your options are make it a variable on `self` or make it an argument to `onComplete` (like this: `def onComplete(self,futures,busy_msg):`) and then pass `future.add_done_callback` a [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) (like so: `future.add_done_callback(functools.partial(self.onComplete, busy_msg=busy);`).

Comment: On the pickling error: ProcessPoolExecutor is using the multiprocessing module, and the arguments have to be picklable. Specifically here `self.returnData` isn't going to work -- the easiest thing to do is pass a module level function instead of an instance method. You can submit arguments to be passed to the function instead of having it access the instance variables, i.e. `executor.submit(return_data_function, arg1, arg2 ...)`. Everything you pass, and whatever is returned, should be picklable.

Comment: You don't need the multiprocessing module or the ProcessPoolExecutor and all their pickling fun.  Just use a ThreadPoolExecutor.